# How to get a stack trace of a caught error?

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling

When my app launches, I do something like:

```
do {
    try complexStartUpRoutine()
} catch let error {
    fatalError("Failed to launch: \(error)")
}
```

The function `complexStartUpRoutine` contains many places where errors could be thrown without being caught, and in addition, many errors are thrown and caught, and this is perfectly okay. Only the uncaught errors cause the fatal error.

Sometimes while developing, I might introduce a bug or incorrectly modify an asset which causes `complexStartUpRoutine` to throw an error, and I get the contents of the error printed to the console as part of the call to `fatalError`.

Unfortunately, the thrown error is usually one which could have happened anywhere, and by itself doesn't really help me to track down where it happened. What I really want is a stack trace at the time that error was thrown, but I'm not sure how to get it:

- Breaking on all Swift errors doesn't really help much, as there are many valid try/catches which occur within `complexStartUpRoutine`, and I want to ignore those. Only the error which causes `complexStartUpRoutine` to throw matters.
- Breaking on only the specific error (by setting the 'Type' of the 'Swift Error' breakpoint) which is reported in `fatalError` only helps very slightly, because the same error might be thrown and caught hundreds of times as part of the complex function. Additionally, I've only had a small amount of luck getting the breakpoint to work in this way anyway.

Is there a way I can get Xcode to break at the moment the error is thrown but isn't caught within `complexStartUpRoutine`?